# Retrieveing data from database results in 0 results

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've got multiple entries in my database, yet my php code `returns 0` entries.

Here's my php:

```html
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $databasename);

// Check connection can be established
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT charts_URL, charts_date, charts_retrace, charts_start_of_swing_trade, charts_end_of_swing_trade, charts_bull_flag, charts_bear_flag, charts_ema_crossover, charts_trading_instrument FROM charts";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result && $result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
  echo "
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td><strong><u>Chart</u></strong></td>
         <td><strong><u>Date</u></strong></td>
         <td><strong><u>Retrace</u></strong></td>
         <td><strong><u>Start of Swing Trade</u></strong></td>
         <td><strong><u>End of Swing Trade</u></strong></td>
         <td><strong><u>Bull flag</u></strong></td>
         <td><strong><u>Bear flag</u></strong></td>
         <td><strong><u>EMA Crossover</u></strong></td>
         <td><strong><u>Trading Instrument</u></strong></td>
       </tr>";
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        echo  "<tr><td><a href=" . $row['charts_URL']. "><img src=". $row['charts_URL']. "></a></td>";
        echo  "<td>" . $row['charts_date']. "</td>";
        echo  "<td>" . $row["charts_retrace"]. "</td>";
        echo  "<td>" . $row["charts_start_of_swing_trade"]. "</td>";
        echo  "<td>" . $row["charts_end_of_swing_trade"]. "</td>";
        echo  "<td>" . $row["charts_bull_flag"]. "</td>";
        echo  "<td>" . $row["charts_bear_flag"]. "</td>";
        echo  "<td>" . $row["charts_ema_crossover"]. "</td>";
        echo  "<td>" . $row["charts_trading_instrument"]. "</td></tr>";
    }
     echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();   
?>
```

Obviously, I cut out the actual database info such as username, password, etc.  Here's a snippet from my php code that I used to submit data into the database which submits data successfully into the database.

```html
 $sql = "INSERT into charts (charts_URL, charts_date, charts_retrace, charts_start_of_swing_trade, charts_end_of_swing_trade, charts_bullflag, charts_bearflag, charts_ema_crossover, charts_trading_instrument) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

So you can double check the variables between my data retrieval/display code and my data insertion code.  My data insertion code works perfectly.  I see data inthe database that I submitted through a form.  But when I try and retrieve the data and display it, I get a "0 results" message.   Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried echo $sql and run the actual query on the database?

Comment: nope didn't try that but great idea though.  I actually got it working now so it's all good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue #1**
You have typos in your query

```
INSERT ... charts_bullflag, charts_bearflag ...
SELECT ... charts_bull_flag, charts_bear_flag ...
```

You have extra `_` in 2 of your column names in your `SELECT`

**Issue #2**
You are doing the `fetch_array()` on your query string

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
```

You need to do it on your query result - `$result`

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
```

or since you are using OOP style for your query, you could also do your loop in OOP style

```
while ($row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
```

Comment: This is irrelevent since the code never gets that far, if fails the IF and goes to the else I believe.

Comment: @DavidSoussan so you are saying that `while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))` is correct? It may not be the only issue, but it is definitely not irrelevant.

Comment: I am saying that it is irrelevent to the OP question. When OP gets to the next problem then OP can post a new question as per the way that StackOverflow works, or is supposed to work.

Comment: changed it to `while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))` but still 0 results.  That solution made sence because I was trying to fetch results from a query instead of the $results variable first which was actually fetching the results. But I still get 0 results.

Comment: @DavidSoussan I have updated with the error in the `SELECT` query. Now this addressed both issues, rather than having the OP bloat SO with another question that is just a typographical issue.

Comment: @Thomas I have updated my answer with your issue in your `SELECT` query. The error would cause the query to fail, which would give you `0 results`. You can debug this by using [`$conn->error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: Genius!  How the heck did I miss the typo errors....  Anyways, it finally displayed the data.  Thanks man!  I'll give David some credit too.  His solution for the error checking actually gave me the error message that one of my fields was unknown or whatever which Sean actually mentioned.

Comment: But what I also find curious is.....only 2 fields had typo errors.  Why did it still give 0 results?  Why couldn't it fetch the results for the other fields?

Comment: If there is any error in the query - wrong column name, typo/syntax error, etc - then the query fails, and 0 results are returned. In your case, since it could not find your unknown columns, it does not find any rows that match.

Comment: @Sean NO. It never gets to the test for zero rows. If $result is false then no other test in the IF is processed. Otherwise you would get an Exception for method on non-object re: $result->num_rows because you do  NOT have a result object, only a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
```

To

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
```

The correct syntax is

```
mysqli_fetch_array(result,resulttype);
```

$sql contains just a string of the query.

UPDATE:
And also change

```
 if($result && $result->num_rows > 0) {
```

to

```
if($result === false)
{
   echo mysqli_error($conn);
}
else if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
{
 // Display result
}
else
{
 // 0 results...
}
```

Comment: changed it to `while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))` but still 0 results.

Comment: Check my updated answer, I hope that works..!

Comment: @Nandan changing to not eqauls false does nothing, it is symantically the same test. What you need to do is to check that the query succeeded ON ITS OWN. See my extended answer for more information.

Comment: You are right @David Soussan, $result will be false only if the query execution fails, not when it shows 0 results. So technically it has to be checked independently.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are checking for $result, if it is false then you will get your else `echo "0 results";`

So you need to check what the error was

```
if($result === false){
    echo mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

After engaging in a comment chat on other answers I have decided to expand and explain the real problem here.

If your query fails then mysqli query will return false. This will terminate the rest of the processing of the IF statement without processing the other conditions; in this case $result->num_rows().

Many people make the mistake of thinking that it is the num_rows that is zero, forgetting that this test was never even run. So it is a bad idea, ie. difficult to debug, to include multiple conditions in an IF on a query result.

First check that the query succeeded by just testing for $result === false: and be as explicit as you can be in your code  by writing it exactly like that so no-one can misinterpret your intentions.

Then when you do get a false return from your query you can debug the error and fix the query. After that you can worry about not getting the query results you expected, ie more than zero rows.

Have a read of the manual and the comments for how to trap and process query errors http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php as there are many ways to do this; and many ways to do this in development as oposed to production, because we hope that all of this is fixed before going into production.